# Use of customer's logo on digital product demo

Tags: trademark

I'm looking to email prospective customer's a screenshot of a demo website that I've setup for them. I'd like to include their logo within the screenshot of the website.

I was wondering if this violates US trademark law.

The demo website, with their logo in the header, would only be available to them with a password and would not be used/seen by anyone else.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't ask them for permission?

Comment: Is this unsolicited? Seems like a very strange thing to do (the whole set up a website, logo and all, and send a password protected demo to them) completely unsolicited.